# Can someone explain how to get the minimal polynomial for this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

This is example 8.45 from Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*. $T$
is the operator on $\mathbb{C}^5$ whose matrix with respect to the standard basis is:\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0
\end{matrix}
Find the minimal polynomial of $T$.
The solution is supposed to be $z^5-6z+3$ but I don't understand the steps to get to this.

Comment: This is the [companion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) matrix for $X^5-6X+3$. A general proof can be done by expansion of the determinant in the first row and induction. This is a concrete example, though, so you can just compute it. Write $I-tA$ and use your favourite definition of the determinant.

Comment: @guidoar This question is not about the characteristic polynomial; there is no point in computing any determinant.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen it's a companion matrix, they coincide.

Comment: @guidoar I know, but the question was not about the characteristic polynomial. To show that they coincide, you need to know what the minimal polynomial is (and also what the characteristic polynomial is, which is in fact harder).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen agreed (also, I know you know). I didn't think my original comment through thoroughly, the wording could have been better. On a related note; isn't the accepted answer wrong? It only shows the desired polynomial vanishes at $A$

Comment: You are right about the (currently) accepted answer not addressing the minimality of the proposed annihilator polynomial, so I wrote a more complete answer that does do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) this is obvious.

If not, you can compute the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and get $\chi_A(x)=x^5-6x+3$.  Since $A$ has no repeated eigenvalues, a fact you can easily check with the roots of $\chi'_A(x)=5x^4-6$ (or use Eisenstein criterion), the minimal polynomial coincide with characteristic polynomial.

Or you can show by direct computation that $T^4,T^3,T^2,T,I$ are linearly independent (look at where $e_1$ got sent to).  Hence the minimal polynomial must be a quintic, etc.

Comment: I have not yet learned about companion matrices. Aren't the eigenvalues here 1 with multiplicity of 4 and -3 with multiplicity of 1? So shouldn't the characteristic polynomial be $(x-1)^4(x+3)$?

Comment: No.  Why should off-diagonal entries give you the eigenvalues?

Comment: I was thinking you could do row reduction, but never mind. A little Googling helped me figure out that that's not allowed. Sorry, it's been a while since I've done computational linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_n$ be the column vector with all $0$'s except for a $1$ in the $n$-th column from the top, for $n=1,2,3,4,5$. Then $Te_1=e_2$, $Te_2=e_3$, $Te_3=e_4$, $Te_4=e_5$, and $Te_5=-3e_1+6e_2$. Therefore,
$$
                T^5e_1=-3e_1+6Te_1 \\
                (T^5-6T+3I)e_1=0.
$$
By applying powers of $T$, you can conclude that $(T^5-6T+3I)e_k=0$ for $k=1,2,3,4,5$. $p(\lambda)=\lambda^5-6\lambda+3$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of specificity (i.e., more generally) assume the final column has entries $c_0,\ldots,c_4$; here is how one can show that the minimal polynomial is $X^5-c_4X^4-c_3X^3-c_2X^2-c_1X-c_0$. Since the first $4$ columns of the matrix are equal to the last $4$ columns of the identity matrix $I_5$, in other words column $j$ equals the standard basis vector $e_{j+1}$ for $j=1,2,3,4$, one has (by induction if you will) $T^j(e_1)=e_{j+1}$ for those $j$ (and also for $j=0$), and the final column gives $T^5(e_1)=T(e_5)=c_0e_1+c_2e_2++c_2e_3+c_3e_4+c_4e_5$. [This is a nice point to remark that the habit of numbering things, like standard basis vectors and columns, from $1$ rather than $0$ is unfortunate.]

Now consider annihilating polynomials $P$ of $T$, namely those for which $P[T]=0$. A necessary condition for this (i.e., a weaker condition) is that $P[T](e_1)=0$. If $P$ were a nonzero polynomal of degree${}<5$, then this gives a nontrivial relation between $T^j(e_1)$ for $j=0,1,2,3,4$, but those are the standard basis vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5$ which are linearly independent; this cannot happen. On the other hand we do have (by the computation of $T^5(e_1)$) that $P[T](e_1)=0$ for $P=X^5-c_4X^4-c_3X^3-c_2X^2-c_1X-c_0$, and for no other monic polynomial of degree$~5$. So we know that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is certainly not of degree${}<5$, and if it is of degree$~5$ then it must be the mentioned polynomial.

It remains to show that $P[T]=0$ for that polynomial, in other words that $P[T](v)=0$ for any $v\in\Bbb C^5$, not just for $v=e_1$. Since the vectors $T^j(e_1)$ for $j=0,1,2,3,4$ span $\Bbb C^5$, there is a (unique) polynomial $Q$ of degree${}<5$ such that $v=Q[T](e_1)$. Then
$$P[T](v)=P[T](Q[T](e_1)) =(PQ)[T](e_1) =Q[T](P[T](e_1)) =Q[T](0)=0,$$ since $Q[T]$ is a linear map. QED.